# Undefined is not an object (evaluating '_PushTokenManager.default.getDevicePushTokenAsync [REACT NATIVE EXPO]

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, expo

Can't get the token with the getExpoPushTokenAsync() function on expo-notifications api.
The function as follow is just identical to Expo documentation:

```js
import Constants from "expo-constants";
import * as Notifications from "expo-notifications";
import * as Permissions from "expo-permissions";

async function registerForPushNotificationsAsync() {
    let token;
    if (Constants.isDevice) {
    const { status: existingStatus } = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
    let finalStatus = existingStatus;
    if (existingStatus !== 'granted') {
        const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
        finalStatus = status;
    }
    if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {
        alert('Failed to get push token for push notification!');
        return;
    }
    token = (await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()).data;
    console.log(token);
    } else {
        alert('Must use physical device for Push Notifications');
    }

    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync('default', {
        name: 'default',
        importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
        vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
        lightColor: '#FF231F7C',
    });
    }

    return token;
}
```

Expo: ~37.0.3
App.json:

```
"expo": {
        "android": {
          "useNextNotificationsApi": true
        }
      }
```

Seems like when calling the function, got the next warning:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_PushTokenManager.default.getDevicePushTokenAsync')]
```

Comment: Are you doing this on a real device or an emulator?

Comment: Real device with the Expo App in Android

Comment: Can anyone got a solution to this issue? Why we need to use the 'expo' module and not 'expo-notifications' as the documentation states.

Comment: Well, after long research, finally got a solution for this.
In effect, expo documentation says import * as Notifications from 'expo-notifications';  but actually works with import { Notifications } from "expo";

Also, you must be logged in expo cli. 
Check this: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/7831#issuecomment-613647709

Comment: same problem here. did you find a solution? (managed workflow)

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you import {Notifications} from 'expo' and not the other way from 'expo-notifications'.
Was having the same problem but then tried importing it from the 'expo' and it worked.
[Check out this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQe9X.png)

Comment: Same issue persist

Comment: This is using LegacyNotifications as described here. https://docs.expo.io/versions/v38.0.0/sdk/legacy-notifications/

Comment: Same issue in react native project after ejecting from expo

Answer (score 1):

make sure you are in managed workflow, if you are in bare you should specify
{ experienceId}

code example from the docs:

```
    import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import * as Notifications from 'expo-notifications';

export async function registerForPushNotificationsAsync(userId: string) {
  let experienceId = undefined;
  if (!Constants.manifest) {
    // Absence of the manifest means we're in bare workflow
    experienceId = '@username/example';
  }
  const expoPushToken = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync({
    experienceId,
  });
  await fetch('https://example.com/', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      userId,
      expoPushToken,
    }),
  });
}
```

experienceId (string) -- The ID of the experience to which the token should be attributed. Defaults to Constants.manifest.id exposed by expo-constants. In the bare workflow, you must provide a value which takes the shape @username/projectSlug, where username is the Expo account that the project is associated with, and projectSlug is your slug from app.json

for more info: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#dailytriggerinput

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I wasn't logged into Expo (using expo client).

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answer helped me. I had to change my import statement from

- `import { Notifications } from 'expo';`

to

- `import * as Notifications from 'expo-notifications';`

Comment: import Constants from 'expo-constants';
const projectId = Constants.expoConfig.extra.eas.projectId;
const expoPushToken = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync({
  projectId
});

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
import * as Notifications from 'expo-notifications';
```

This should work